# Losing focus on parent element when hovering child element in prototype

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

I have a div where when I hover over it I have a child div (another div) to animate, but when I hover over the child div, the parent div loses focus and the child element starts animating back as if I left the parent div.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$$(".slide .item").each(function (element) {
    element.observe('mouseover', function (event) {
        element.writeAttribute('doing_animation', 'true');
        element.down('.meta').morph('margin: 103px 0 0;', {
            duration: 0.25,
            afterFinish: function (event) {
                element.writeAttribute('doing_animation', 'false');
            }
        });
    });
    element.observe('mouseout', function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.down('.meta').morph('margin: 169px 0 0;', {
                duration: 0.25
            });
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="meta">
        <h3><a href="#">Space Kitty Needz Moar Balls</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>From: <a href="#">Jeffdoe</a></li>
            <li>Posted: 20 minutes ago</li>
            <li>Views: 249,209</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="images/tmp/kitty.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

So with the code, I would like to hover `.item` OR `.item .meta` and the `.meta` div will still control focus of the `.item` div. I know jQuery does a better job with this, but I need to use Prototype.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you said that you need to use prototype & not jQuery, but just in case you didn't know, you can use both of them on the one page as long as you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, which will return the `$` function back to prototype.js (leaving only the `jQuery` function exposed).

Comment: I don't want to load the full jQuery library for this one thing, so I went ahead and migrated all my code to jQuery on a Rails project. Although I have ran into this problem many times before so I am still curious how to do this with Prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$$(".slide .item").each(function (element) {
    element.observe('mouseover', function (event) {
        var relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget || event.fromElement);
        var target = Event.element(event);
        if ((target == element || Element.descendantOf(target, element))
            && !((relatedTarget == element) || Element.descendantOf(relatedTarget, element)))
        {
            element.writeAttribute('doing_animation', 'true');
            element.down('.meta').morph('margin: 103px 0 0;', {
                duration: 0.25,
                afterFinish: function (event) {
                    element.writeAttribute('doing_animation', 'false'); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
    element.observe('mouseout', function (event) {
        var relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget || event.fromElement);
        var target = Event.element(event);
        if ((target == element || Element.descendantOf(target, element))
            && !((relatedTarget == element) || Element.descendantOf(relatedTarget, element)))
        {
            setTimeout(function () {
                element.down('.meta').morph('margin: 169px 0 0;', {
                    duration: 0.25
                });
            }, 250);
        }
    });
});
```

You can see I've just added a wrapper

```
    var relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget || event.fromElement);
    var target = Event.element(event);
    if ((target == element || Element.descendantOf(target, element))
        && !((relatedTarget == element) || Element.descendantOf(relatedTarget, element)))
    {
        ...
    }
```

around your event handlers.  So, only consider it a "real" mouse-in or mouse-out if we're really moving in or out of the parent container.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to add `mouseover` listener to `.item.` children and clear the `mouseout` timeout in it. Code below is for illustration only - it's untested and the variable should, of course, be appropriately scoped:

```
var timeout = null;

$$(".slide .item").each(function (element) {
    element.observe('mouseout', function (event) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            ...
        }, 250);
    });

    element.descendants().each(function (nested) { 
        nested.observe('mouseover', function (nestedEvent) {
            if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        });
    });
});
```